# Why does my Angular attribute is updated only when I call a postMessage() method from my iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, refresh, parent

I have an attribute called `counter` that I want to be increased by 1 everytime I click on a button in my iframe.

Here is my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fznrnf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

`app.component.ts` :

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  counter = 0;

  @HostListener('window:message', ['$event']) onPostMessage() {
    console.log('Message received');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;

    iframe?.addEventListener('load', () => {
      let iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

      if (iframeWindow) {
        const doc = iframeWindow?.document;

        doc.getElementById('iframeButton')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.counter++;

          window?.postMessage('update ?', '*');
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`app.component.html` :

```html
<iframe
  id="iframe"
  srcdoc="<button id='iframeButton'>Increase my counter !</button>"
></iframe>

<p>Counter = {{ counter }}</p>
```

Now, I want to understand why I need the `window?.postMessage('update ?', '*');` and the `@HostListener` to have my `counter` to increase, and specifically, what **really** happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 2):

[`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is a Web API, that allows communication between windows. So if you have a web page and an iframe using `postMessage` you can facilitate a communication between those two windows.

I played a bit with your project. When you comment out the `window?.postMessage('update ?', '*');` and clicking the button, the counter property on `AppComponent` is getting incremented, but the Angular is not responding to the change.

My guess is that increment is running outside of Angular's change detection system. On the other hand when when you also do a `postMessage` the change detection is triggered correctly, because `@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])` will take care of that.

If you update your component as follows, it will display increment of your `counter` property in `AppComponent`.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  counter = 0;

  constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  @HostListener('window:message', ['$event']) onPostMessage() {
    console.log('Message received');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;

    iframe?.addEventListener('load', () => {
      let iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

      if (iframeWindow) {
        const doc = iframeWindow?.document;

        doc.getElementById('iframeButton')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.counter++;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
          // window?.postMessage('update ?', '*');
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Calling `this.cd.detectChanges();` will ask Angular explicitly to run change detection thus will display the counter update.

---

**Extended answer:**

Will try to explain in more details, what I think is going on under the hood.

Your application have two "contexts". Main window, in which the Angular app is running and then iframe window, which is just plain HTML.

[Per article about change detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) you've mentioned in the comment, in the main window Angular is patching browser API, such as `addEventListener`, `setTimeout`, etc. to be able to detect changes, that should be rendered in the view.

But the iframe window does not have it's API patched.

So if you click button within the iframe to increment `counter`, the view is not updated (although AppComponent property is). Click handler in your iframe is not patched to trigger Angular change detection and to update the view.

To let Angular know, that something in the view was updated from "the outside" we need to call change detection explicitly by `this.cd.detectChanges();`.

But if you do a `postMessage` from iframe window, a message handler `onPostMessage()` in main window is triggered. Message handler in the main window is patched by Angular, so when the message event is received the change detection is kicked off, `counter` increment is detected and the view is updated.

Comment: The keywords here seem to be "Angular change detection system", and the ChangeDetectorRef helps with that, so thank you ! I found this Angular blogpost https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/ which explains some part of it. So, while I still don't know exactly what happens, I understand a little bit more ^^

Comment: The link you've attached explains the change detection pretty well. So I will try to extend my answer, let me know if it brings more light on that is happening under the hood.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found a case where the postMessage() works, but the detectChanges() don't...But it will probably be for another question.

Comment: The answer is updated, is it more clear, what is going on now?

Comment: Yes it is more clear, thanks, I think I understood the same thing when reading the article. The thing that I struggle with now is a bit more complex (the stackblitz example was a simple one and I thought that it represented exactly what I wanted but it seems that it doesn't). My problem is about a scroll event with the PDF.js viewer solution by Mozilla which use an iframe, that I want to customize from an Angular component. I will try to put my exact problem on stackblitz, but I'm not sure I can because the PDF.js viewer contain some big files. I will probably ask another question then ^^'